# Selenium webdriver. Reading an earlier line

Tags: c#, selenium

Trying to automatize a couple of tests for our projects using the selenium webdriver and C# and i got into the following situation:
When i try to test the main menu the flow goes something like this:

1. Click on  the first menu item (located on top of the page)
2. Wait for the last element in the page to load so i can make sure the content is fully loaded (sometimes it takes 15-20 seconds for a full page load)
3. Assert the title text which is located in a div under the main menu
4. Click on the next menu item and continue with a similar flow

Now my problem is that after the page is loaded and the test must assert the title text (3), i get a crash. I understand that this is happening because C# only reads the content once and can't return to a previous element once it read it.
So my solution that i thought would get me out was to first define the body tag in a variable and then call it for assert and further navigation:

```
var body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")); 

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")).Click();    // click on the first item in the main menu
driver.WaitForElement(By.XPath("/html/path_to_the_last/div[1]"));    // waiting for the last element on the page
Assert.AreEqual("Title text", body.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div")).Text.Trim());     // assert the title text by calling the initially set variable

body.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]")).Click();   // click on the next item in the main menu.
// similar flow to follow until each menu was checked
```

The thing is that when the webdriver is about to execute the assert - where the variable was first called, it crashes with the following error:

> *OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up*

Any idea what i did wrong and how should i proceed?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your problem, but can't you really identify elements any other way than xpath with **11** nested divs? Maybe id's? Classes? Names?

Comment: First, this is not a good way to write xpath anyway. I am not sure how your html looks like. The issue could be specific to the selector. Provide some more info with html snippet

Comment: `C# only reads the content once and can't return to a previous element once it read it.` so what problem did you get that made you think this (it's wrong BTW)? You've shown us what you did to try to overcome that problem but not what exceptions & error messages you got initially.

Comment: @JoriO, i would if all the divs had classes, names or ids but they don't, so i have to go through the whole nest. Luckily for me, firebug gets the whole path right with a simple right click.

Comment: @Arran - am i wrong about that statement? i came to this conclusion when the test couldn't click on a button from the top of the page after it had to wait for the final div to load. The error i got is "Element not found in cache", did you mean something else?

Comment: @radu no you are incorrect. The error you have given is not to do with C# but rather specifically Selenium. The problem is when a page changes, in any way, Selenium trashes the reference to your previous elements. This is generally because Selenium has no idea how the page has changed, but just "its changed", so puts the responsibility on you, the programmer, to keep up-to-date references to DOM elements. So you have the right concept, but this is a Selenium-specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when finding items from body-element, your path can't start from the root. So in the assert you should have this:

```
body.FindElement(By.XPath("./div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div")
```

There the beginning dot means your body-element.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve my problem. Something that i did not mentioned before (although it's not that relevant) is that the content posted is located within a frame. So a solution that works but i find it ugly is to switch to the default content and then back to the iframe, right before the assert line. Using a tag variable that i can call whenever i want to go back on top would be so much more helpful